# Type 'AxMSChart20Lib.AxMSChart' is not defined. error

Tags: vb.net, com

I have an old 2005 project in VB.NET that should use AxMSChart20Lib COM library. Can anyone appoint me to a download location (a working one) or explain to me how to construct the lib? 
Thank you

Comment: It is an auto-generated .NET wrapper, created by Aximp.exe, for the ancient mschrt20.ocx control.  Very hard to obtain these days, you can still get VB6 from an MSDN subscription.  Beware the security updates btw.  You don't want to have to maintain this, get ahead with the .NET Chart control.